# I want to know a sentence meaning (between "")

Tags: learning

Well, no. Not something dangerous, like an electric shock. I mean experiencing a sudden and unpleasant change from "what you have been used to"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. What is 'Between ""?'

Comment: Are you asking what the significance is of a phrase being in quotes "like this", or are you asking what the meaning of "what you have been used to" is?

Comment: "What you have been used to" = "the usual". A sudden and unpleasant change from the usual. Or just drop it altogether. The word "change" already implies that all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

a **jolt**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jolt)

> an emotional shock; To make suddenly active or effective:

As in:

The remark *jolted* my memory.

Comment: thanks TRomano . the sentence is understandable for me after your comment. 

Answer (score 0):

"what you have been used to" = that which you have grown accustomed to.

Not an electric shock, but "shock" in the sense of a sudden and unpleasant change from your normal existence which you take for granted because you've become accustomed to it.